# How duplicate web requests on to multiple servers?

Tags: iis, httprequest, windows-server-2012

We have a memory leak that is difficult to duplicate outside of production. We were thinking that it would be best if we had a duplicate server where the responses are ignored, that receives all the same requests as the primary server. Our web server is IIS. Is there any way to do this in a Windows server environment?

Comment: 1. Are you trying to run it on two servers for redundancy/fail-over or for observation?  2. Are you looking for a SW solution or would you consider some routing or HW config?

Comment: I'm not looking for a fail-over, I just want to duplicate the usage to reproduce the problem and run analysis utilities without interfering with production. We don't care if it's a HW and SW solution

Comment: That was supposed to read, we don't care if it's a HW _or_ a SW solution